# onbeforeunload not working when another script added

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I have this little piece of code to check if there were any changes in form fields before leaving page

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var form = $('#submit-form'),
        original = form.serialize();
    form.submit(function(){
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function(){

        if (form.serialize() != original)
            return 'Changes detected';
    };
});
```

It worked fine. Then I integrated [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) into my page and above script is not working anymore. If i comment out line with tag-it.js is included it works again. I'm pretty ignorant when it comes to javascript and I have no idea why it isn't working.

Here's the link to tag-it.js script (which btw is pretty nice)

https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/js/tag-it.js

EDIT:

By not working I mean there's isn't any popup winow if I edit the form and want to leave the page anymore.

If I don't include tag-it.js file (linked above) everything works fine and i get popup window when I edit the form and try to leave the page.

Comment: can you elaborate on "not working anymore"? are there any errors? does it just do nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You should check if window.onbeforeunload is already defined if yes then you can

call older one as below:
 // first file

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){

            if (form.serialize() != original)
                return 'Changes detected';
        };
    // other file
    var olderonbeforeunload = window.onbeforeunload;

    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
           if(typeof olderonbeforeunload == 'function'){
           olderonbeforeunload.apply(arguments);
         }
           // new code
        };
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I don't think I know what to do with your answer @Shusl should I put it into the tag-it.js file? and replace // new code with with those `if` and `return` lines?